# Does every finitely axiomatizable theory have irredundant bases of every finite cardinality?

Tags: first-order-logic, model-theory

Let $T$ be a finitely axiomatizable first-order theory, and let $n$ be an arbitrary positive integer. An axiom set $A$ for $T$ is defined to be irredundant iff $A$ has no redundant axioms. My question is, does $T$ always have an irredundant axiom set whose cardinality is $n$?

Answer (score 6):

Here's a partial result: the answer is positive if $T$ has no finite models.

Let $\theta$ be a single sentence axiomatizing $T$ and fix $n>1$. Consider the following set of axioms:

- "If there are more than $n-1$ elements in the universe, then $\theta$."
- "There is not exactly $1$ element in the universe."
- "There are not exactly $2$ elements in the universe."
- ...
- "There are not exactly $n-1$ elements in the universe."

This is an independent axiomatization of $T$ consisting of $n$ sentences.

We can push this basic idea to a much wider class of theories. However, note that some restriction is necessary: the empty theory has no irredundant axiomatizations of any cardinality $>0$. More generally, if there are only $k$ structures (up to elementary equivalence) which **don't** satisfy $T$, then $T$ can't have an irredundant axiomatization of size $>k$ (think about the role of sentences in an axiomatization of $T$ as ruling out non-models).

Comment: hi Noah, +1 of course! I think we can get a converse to the point you make in your last paragraph, right? suppose there are at least $k+1$ structures not satisfying $T$; call them $M_1,\dots,M_{k+1}$. for each $i\neq j$, choose a sentence $\phi_{ij}$ satisfied by $M_i$ and not by $M_j$. define $\psi_i=\bigwedge_{j\neq i}\phi_{ij}$ for each $i\leqslant k$. then the axiomatization consisting of $\neg\psi_i$ for each $i\leqslant k$, and the single sentence $\left(\bigwedge_{i\leqslant k}\neg\psi_i\right)\to\theta$, should I think do the trick, right?

Comment: (so this would give a full characterization – $T$ has an irredundant axiomatization of size $n$ if and only if it has at least $n$ models, up to elementary equivalence)

Comment: @AtticusStonestrom Seems like a complete answer to me! But you mean $T$ has at least $n$ *non-models*.

Comment: Oh, and you want $\lnot\psi_i$ to not rule out any models of $\theta$.

Comment: I think that with the next edit the answer will be put into complete form. The answer could be expressed in terms of the structure of the Lindenbaum-Tarski algebra of first-order sentences modulo $T$, or in terms of the LT algebra of first-order sentences of the language modulo the empty theory. Then the question reduces to a question about independent meets in a Boolean algebra.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another partial result. Assume that $T$ is not axiomatisable by the empty set, and that your language contains infinitely many unary predicate symbols $Q_0,Q_1,\ldots$

Then the answer is *yes*:

Let $A$ be some finite nonempty axiomatisation of $T$. Then $\{\bigwedge A\}$ is an irredundant axiom set for $T$ of size $1$. On the other hand, whenever you have some irredundant axiom set $A\cup\{\theta\}$ for $T$ of size $n>0$, then $A\cup\{(\exists x Q_i(x))\lor\theta,(\lnot\exists x Q_i(x))\lor\theta\}$ is an irredundant axiom set for $T$ of size $n+1$, where $Q_i$ is some predicate not occuring in $A\cup\{\theta\}$. In this way you get irredundant sets of arbitrary positive size.